# AWS SageMaker: CapacityError: Unable to provision requested ML compute capacity.

Tags: tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker

We were running two TrainingJob instances of type (1) *ml.p3.8xlarge* and (2) *ml.p3.2xlarge* .

Each training job is running a custom algorithm with Tensorflow plus a Keras backend.

The instance (1) is running ok, while the instance (2) after a reported time of training of 1 hour, with any logging in CloudWatch (any text tow log), exits with this error:

```
Failure reason
CapacityError: Unable to provision requested ML compute capacity. Please retry using a different ML instance type.
```

I'm not sure what this message mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This message mean SageMaker tried to launch the instance but EC2 was not having enough capacity of this instance hence after waiting for some time(in this case 1 hour) SageMaker gave up and failed the training job.

For more information about capacity issue from ec2, please visit: 
[troubleshooting-launch-capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting-launch.html#troubleshooting-launch-capacity)

To solve this, you can either try running jobs with different instance type as suggested in failure reason or wait a few minutes and then submit your request again as suggested by EC2.